# mysql multiple rows to one

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get a table with multiple data from the same column.
This is my Table:

```
ID   name     value   month
1    foo      1,2     01
2    foo      1,3     02
3    chicken  0,6     01
4    chciken  0,4     02
```

My goal is to get something like this:

```
name     value   value2  
foo      1,2     1,3
chicken  0,6     0,4
```

my goal is to compare the values of every month.

Comment: Do all of them have always exactly 2 values with `month` column equal to `01` and `02`? PS: It's so ugly to store a month number in a (var)char column.

Comment: atm there are exactly 2 rows per name but i plan to expand it with more monthly data, every row has `month` `value` `name` `ID` filled

Comment: So suddenly you want a value3 column... Check out PIVOT functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**

```
SELECT name, 
MAX(CASE WHEN month='01' THEN value END) As value1, 
MAX(CASE WHEN month='02' THEN value END) As value2 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY name;
```